# Why does Chrome (v.51.0.2704.106 m) ignore "@meda all and (max-width:849)?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I don't find any explanation why my media query does not work in chrome. It works as expected in Firefox and Safari, but in Chrome noe media query is working.

This is how i linked it in my html. I also tried it without media="all" but it doesn't work.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="/webresources/css/styles~2016-07-28-09-01-05-000~cache.css"
media="all">

</head>
<body>

</body></html>
```

My sass/scss looks like this and i'm not getting an error while transform to css with an gulp task.

```
@media all and (max-width: 1200px) {

}

@media all and (max-width: 849px) {

}
```

The strange thing is that the first media query is used but the second one, that should override the first one, isn't used.

[This is the style which is used on width: 800px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7n9S.png)

I also looked in the source if some code is missing, but all media querys are there.

[Here i found the idea of problems with link and media query, but this didn't help](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/P-Npluex6iA)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this record try? Or equivalent.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

Usually I write:

```
@media screen and (max-height: 26.375em){}
```

And have no problem.

Comment: Thanks, used this one: 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
And this works also with "@media all"